# Word for someone who unnecessarily/unlawfully accuses another

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: Person A alleges without proof that person B infringed on the rights of person C. Person A has nothing to gain or lose.

The closest I got is [champerty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/champerty), but here person A has something to gain.

> The investing of money into an individual's lawsuit.

There's also [denunciator](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denunciator), but it doesn't capture the essence of the A-B-C relation.

> One who denounces, publishes, or proclaims, especially intended or coming evil; one who threatens or accuses.

In the context of defense, not accusation, there's [white knight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/white_knight#English), which is also derogatory. Colloquially, it's the closest, but it's not right.

> Someone who unnecessarily defends someone else.

---

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable (note: it was suggested I mention that in the new asking dialog).

---

Based on the [first answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/526965/369255):

A "**slanderer**" *A* harms *B*'s reputation in front of audience *C*.
An "**accuser**" does not necessarily need a C.

Both are not the same as with "white knight" or the A-B-C premise in the question.

---

"Meddler" may come close, if somehow is combined with "accuser".

Comment: Is *unncessarily* or *unlawfully* crucial here? These are two very different concepts. One gets a sense that you are looking for something like *busybody*, but that can't quite be the right answer, because it has nothing to do with lawfulness, and is not limited to accusations. Moreover, what exactly is the kind of 'accusation' that you have in mind: criminal charge, civil lawsuit, or an informal accusation made in gossip? All of them?

Comment: So, you are looking for a term for people who make accusations (1) without proof, (2) unlawfully, (3) about something that does not infringe their own rights, (4) without having anything to gain or lose. There is no term whose meaning combines all four of these elements.

Answer (score 1):

If the person is making a false accusation, they are a **slanderer**. (**Libeller** if done in writing).

If they are making an accusation they are an **accuser**.

Accuser has a number of synonyms which you can check for yourself.